# Product filter with color size price brand in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-5.4

I just made an e-commerce website in Laravel 5.4. I need to make product filter like size price brand price. I never did this before, so do you have any tutorial or basic tutorial?

Comment: Upvoter: please do not upvote questions like this, they should not be encouraged. Readers here expect a minimum of prior effort and research - this question as it stands is very much off-topic, and I would expect it to close in due course. OP, if you can modify the question so it is on-topic, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel where clauses fit you perfectly. Make appropriate database structure and then select products what needed.

```
Product::where('size', 'XL')->get();
```

More info from this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

If you are new to Laravel then start from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation