# Laravel many-to-many relationship grammar error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have 2 tables called products and category. Product belongsToMany category and category belongsToMany products.

Here is my table schema:

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('stock');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('restrict')
                    ->onUpdate('restrict');

        $table->dateTime('published_at');
    });
```

Here is my category table schema

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('categorydesigner_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
                    ->onDelete('restrict')
                    ->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')
                    ->onDelete('restrict')
                    ->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am getting the following error

```
    Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in 

C:\xampp\htdocs\swimwear2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 681
```

Here is my controller

```
public function productpost(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|required',
    ]);

    $designer_name = $request->designer;
    $designer_slug = str_random(40);
    $designer = designer::where('name', $designer_name)->firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => $designer_name], ['slug' => $designer_slug]
        );
    $designer->name = $designer_name;
    $designer->slug = $designer_slug;
    $designer->save();
    $designer_id = $designer->id;
    $product = new Product;
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->designer_id = $designer_id;
    $product->description = $request->description;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->stock = $request->stock;
    $product->gender = $request->gender;
    $product_slug = str_random(40);
    $product->slug = $product_slug;
    $product->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $product->published_at = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        //getting timestamp
        $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/product/', $name);
        $product->image = $name;
        $thumb = Image::make(public_path().'/images/product/' . $name)->resize(1200,1800)->save(public_path().'/images/product/thumb/' . $name, 90);  
    }
    $product->save();
    $productsearch = product::where('slug', $product_slug)->firstorfail();
    $product_id = $productsearch->id;
    $categoryname = $request->category;
    $category = category::where('name', $categoryname)->firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => $categoryname], ['categorydesigner_id' => $designer_id]
        );

    $category->name = $category;

    $category->categorydesigner_id = $designer_id;
    $category->save();

    $category->products()->attach($product_id);
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Post Success');
}
```

My product and designer are added successfully getting error only for category request. designerid is coming fine.

```
$category = category::where('name', $categoryname)->firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => $categoryname], ['categorydesigner_id' => $designer_id]
        );

    $category->name = $category;

    $category->categorydesigner_id = $designer_id;
    $category->save();

    $category->products()->attach($product_id);
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the where clause before your firstOrCreate method? The first parameter will act like a where.
Also remove $category->name, $category->categorydesigner_id and $category->save() lines, these are all unnecessary and might be part of the problem (not sure though).

Comment: thanks it fixed now

Comment: I will submit it as the answer to your question

Comment: Hi Sid. I asked [two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905827/product-filter-with-color-size-price-brand-in-laravel) that urgent/ASAP and other begging phrases are not added to your questions. Please do refrain, thank you! I recommend you read the whole of the following page to understand why we discourage this in questions:

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the where clause before your firstOrCreate method.
The first parameter will act like a where.

Also remove `$category->name`, `$category->categorydesigner_id` and `$category->save()` lines, these are all unnecessary and might be part of the problem.